# ipad-like html scroll component

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm loking for a css/js component similar to [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) but that should also work on non-webkit browsers. More specifically, I want some or all of these requisites:

- thin scrollbar
- scrollbar only appears on drag and/or hover
- support drag for scroll

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery plugins:

- [ClickNScroll](http://sourceforge.net/p/clicknscroll/home/Home/) (claims to also support 'throwing' of the viewport which is a neat feature)
- [Dragscrollable](https://github.com/iwyg/jquery.dragscroll) (last updated 5 days ago as of writing this, so that's a good thing)